# Appending script tag through javascript in DOM and setting its src throws error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to append script tag through JS and set its src. Following is the code:

```
var myscript = document.createElement('script');
myscript.setAttribute('src', 'http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?playerId=player&width=320&amp;height=240&amp;embedCode=thbXMxMzpq0RhOS82Hzx1lma8UMnFN-3&amp;callback=apicallback');
document.getElementById('curr-video').appendChild(myscript);
```

While doing so modern browsers FF,Chrome,Safari works fine.

But IE8,7 throws

> error [ null is null or not an object player.js ]

The video `src` is an ooyala video service.

Is there any solution how can I append script tag and set its src(retrieved from JSON).

Comment: `document.getElementById('curr-video')` doesn't exist.

Comment: Seems like the script is successfully appended, but something within `player.js` is causing the error.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: which is odd, if there's no error thrown by Firefox Chrome and Safari...

Answer (score 0):

IE7 doesn't give error when player.js loads with page but it does when loaded dynamically. Besides if you ignore the error and let the script works, player appears normally. If you insist on to remove error, you can create an iframe and load a player.html page inside it so that you can run your player.js when page loads without error.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createIframe (iframeName, width, height) {
    var iframe;
    if (document.createElement && (iframe = document.createElement('iframe'))) {
            iframe.name = iframe.id = iframeName;
            iframe.width = width;
            iframe.height = height;
            iframe.frameBorder = "0";
            iframe.style.border = "none";
            iframe.src = 'about:blank';
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
    return iframe;
}

function load_item() {
    var iframe = createIframe ('iframe0', 320, 240);
    if (iframe) {
        iframe.src = "player.html";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a onclick="load_item();">click to load</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is player.html:

```
<html>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
<script src="http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?........."></script>
</body>
</html>
```