# Error document.getElementById is null

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing some javascript functions that dynamically create a new iframe and the relative button to delete it.

This is the code that I wrote to create the button:

```js
function addButton(iframeId, num) {
    var butt = document.createElement('button');
    var butt_text = document.createTextNode(num);
    butt.appendChild(butt_text);
    butt.id = num + 100;
    butt.onclick = function() { removeButton(butt.id); removeIframe(iframeId, butt.id); }
    document.body.appendChild(butt);
    numButt++;
}
```

and this is how I call it:

```
addElement(iframe.id, cont);
```

The parameter "cont" is a counter that starts from 1 and is increased in the function to create the new iframe, so the first button will be named 101 and it eliminates iframe #1, the second button will be named 102 and it eliminates frame #2, and so on.

"numButt" is a counter that starts from 0 and counts how many buttons are created, so to know the id of the last created button.

The function to remove the button is this and it works fine:

```js
function removeButton(buttonId) {
    butt = document.getElementById(buttonId);  
    if (butt) { 
        butt.parentNode.removeChild(butt);
    }
}
```

Now I want to reassign the onclick event of the button. Since if I remove the iframe #3 all the iframes.id with id higher than 3 will be renamed with this function (I need to do renaming because my resizeIframe function works with consequential IDs):

```js
function renameIds(elim) {
    for (i = 1; i <= cont; i++) {
        if (i > elim) {
            document.getElementById(i).id = i-1;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to change the onclick event of the button so that button named 104 will eliminate iframe #3, button 105 will eliminate frame #4 and so on.

I make this in the removeIframe function but it doesn't work, since Firefox error console returns me "document.getElementById(a) is null":

```js
function removeIframe(iframeId, buttId) {
    iframe = document.getElementById(iframeId);
    var a;
    if (iframe) {
        iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
        renameIds(iframeId);
        cont--;
        resizeIframe();
        for (a = 101; a <= 100+numButt; a++) {
            if (a > buttId) {
                document.getElementById(a).onclick = function() { removeButton(a); removeIframe(a-101, a); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's the problem??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you give us the html code !

Comment: Sidenote: I think you need to look into jQuery (http://jquery.com/). These kind of functions, and a lot of easy DOM manipulation are all very standard, and it saves you a lot of time.

Comment: where is the code that creates iframe please! the code for add element

Comment: To create iframes look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931765/appending-script-tag-through-javascript-in-dom-and-setting-its-src-throws-error

Answer (score 0):

You should decrease

> numButt

when remove one i.e. numButt--; in function removeButton.

Comment: No I don't need this, because if I create 8 buttons and I remove 3 buttons (for example, 102, 103 and 106) the last button.id is still 108.

Comment: @badetection, then you shouldn't use this variable in removeIframe function in last loop as it's size is obviously large then you need. More over, condition like "if (a > buttId) {" in general for loop looks dummy, especcialy if you take into account that buttId is immutable inside the loop...

Comment: Ok, you're right, but the problem is not that the function misses some IDs, but that it doesn't reassing the onclick event of any button.

Comment: @badetection, yes. And as you mentioned you receive "document.getElementById(a) is null":" which occur due to the fact described above and prevent you code from being execute.